# JavaScript series based control flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, control-flow

In Mixu's Node.js book, there is a very awesome section about control flow.  The following pattern allows you to chain async requests in series to make sure an event has completed before calling the next one.  I'd like to modify this so that the response from one async request can then passed as an argument to the next.

Any ideas?

http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html
http://jsfiddle.net/B7xGn/

```
function series(callbacks, last) {
  var results = [];
  function next() {
    var callback = callbacks.shift();
    if(callback) {
      callback(function() {
        results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        next();
      });
    } else {
      last(results);
    }
  }
  next();
}
// Example task
function async(arg, callback) {
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1) * 100; // random ms
  console.log('async with \''+arg+'\', return in '+delay+' ms');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, delay);
}
function final(results) { console.log('Done', results); }

series([
  function(next) { async(1, next); },
  function(next) { async(2, next); },
  function(next) { async(3, next); },
  function(next) { async(4, next); },
  function(next) { async(5, next); },
  function(next) { async(6, next); }
], final);
```

Comment: You can look into using promises: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Or the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, specifically the `.waterfall()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `next` function signature so that you can pass it a `result`. Here's how you could do it.

```
function series(callbacks, last) {
  var results = [];
  function next(result) {
    var callback = callbacks.shift();
    if(callback) {
      callback(function(result) {
        results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        next(result);
      }, result);
    } else {
      last(results);
    }
  }
  next();
}
// Example task
function async(arg, callback) {
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1) * 100; // random ms
  console.log('async with \''+arg+'\', return in '+delay+' ms');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, delay);
}

function final(results) { console.log('Done', results); }

series([
  function(next) { async(1, next); },
  function(next, result) { console.log('result: ', result); async(2, next); },
  function(next, result) { console.log('result: ', result); async(3, next); },
  function(next, result) { console.log('result: ', result); async(4, next); },
  function(next, result) { console.log('result: ', result); async(5, next); },
  function(next, result) { console.log('result: ', result); async(6, next); }
], final);
```

EDIT:

To be able to pass multiple results, you could simply change the series function to:

```
function series(callbacks, last) {
  var results = [];
  function next() {
    var callback = callbacks.shift(), args;
    if(callback) {
      callback.apply(this, (args = [
        function() {
          results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
          next.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      ]).concat.apply(args, arguments));
    } else {
      last(results);
    }
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: Best. Answer. Ever.  Btw, is there a way to return multiple arguments to the callback and read them in the next function?  Say, callback(2, foo)?

Comment: @4m1r Glad I could help, I have updated the answer to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks again @plalx.  Super cool answer.  Regarding your edit, I was actually trying to find a way of returning from the async with multiple arguments in the callback.  However, since I can just pass an object literal back as the result, this may not be good design.  Regardless, your edit seems to be an even more elegant solution.  In my series, I'm passing the result directly to the next function, e.g async(result, next).  Works great.  You wanna do the world a favor and help us understand exactly what makes this work?

Comment: @4m1r Sure, but could you be more specific on the part that you do not understand exactly and that you find cryptic?

Comment: What's most confusing to me is how the 'next' function is passed as the initial argument to the series, or any of the arguments. Also, how does the compiler know that it should associate and run the next function?  Finally, how would you wrap something like this in another more rudimentary series, say process one series per id in an array slice?

Comment: @4m1r It's not exactly the `next` function that is passed to the series functions, but an anonymous function that contains a call to `next` (the one that contains `results.push(...)`. Within the `next` function, `callback` references one of the series function. We then invoke it using `callback.apply`, which allows us to pass an array of arguments just like if they were passed as seperate arguments. If you look at the code you will see that `next` calls `callback` passing an anonymous function along with all other arguments that were passed to it.

Comment: How is the anonymous next function is called? Well you are passing it as a callback to your own `async` function and this is where it gets invoked. E.g. when you do `async(2, next);`. As for your last question I did not understand it.